# Multiple Select queries with multiple where conditions on MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

My working query is;

```
SELECT SUM(EVET) as Evet,
       SUM(HAYIR) as Hayir,
       SUM(BOS) as Evet,
       SUM(GECERSIZ) as Gecersiz
FROM   sandiklar
WHERE  TUR = 'MM'

UNION

SELECT SUM(EVET),
       SUM(HAYIR),
       SUM(BOS),
       SUM(GECERSIZ)
FROM   sandiklar
WHERE  TUR = 'M'

UNION

SELECT SUM(EVET),
       SUM(HAYIR)r,
       SUM(BOS),
       SUM(GECERSIZ)
FROM   sandiklar
WHERE  TUR = 'MB'
```

The output is:

[image]

My question is;
Can i make that query so that all three rows to be one row with 12 clumns and name clumns according to Where condition.

mmEvet  mmHayir mmBos mmgecersiz mEvet  mHayir mBos mgecersiz mbEvet  mbHayir mbBos mbgecersiz

It would be one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it using a SUM(CASE statement:

```
drop table if exists sandiklar;

create table if not exists sandiklar(tur text, EVET int, HAYIR int, BOS int, GECERSIZ int);

insert into sandiklar values
('MM', 100, 220, 310, 410),
('MM', 110, 230, 320, 420),
('MM', 120, 230, 360, 450),
('M',  110, 210, 370, 420),
('M',  140, 250, 320, 470),
('M',  120, 250, 330, 430),
('MB', 110, 260, 310, 490),
('MB', 150, 210, 310, 430),
('MB', 130, 210, 310, 430);

SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN TUR = 'MM' THEN EVET ELSE 0 END) as EvetMM,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TUR = 'MM' THEN HAYIR ELSE 0 END) as HayirMM,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TUR = 'MM' THEN BOS ELSE 0 END) as EvetMM,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TUR = 'MM' THEN GECERSIZ ELSE 0 END) as GecersizMM,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TUR = 'M' THEN EVET ELSE 0 END) as EvetM,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TUR = 'M' THEN HAYIR ELSE 0 END) as HayirM,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TUR = 'M' THEN BOS ELSE 0 END) as EvetM,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TUR = 'M' THEN GECERSIZ ELSE 0 END) as GecersizM,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TUR = 'MB' THEN EVET ELSE 0 END) as EvetMB,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TUR = 'MB' THEN HAYIR ELSE 0 END) as HayirMB,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TUR = 'MB' THEN BOS ELSE 0 END) as EvetMB,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TUR = 'MB' THEN GECERSIZ ELSE 0 END) as GecersizMB
FROM   sandiklar
WHERE  TUR IN ('MM','M','MB');

drop table if exists sandiklar;

| EvetMM | HayirMM | EvetMM | GecersizMM | EvetM  | HayirM  | EvetM  | GecersizM  | EvetMB | HayirMB | EvetMB | GecersizMB |
|-------:|--------:|--------|------------|--------|---------|--------|------------|--------|---------|--------|------------|
| 330    | 680     | 990    | 1280       | 370    | 710     | 1020   | 1320       | 390    | 680     | 930    | 1350       |
```

I've set up a sample here: http://rextester.com/SIO50162

Comment: Woww. Thats really quick. Is there any performance difference with my multiple select query and yours?

Comment: You can add a `WHERE TUR IN ('MM','M','MB')` if TUR has an index